# An exercise related to strict diagonal dominance

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Here is the original question. The $(i, j)$-entry of the matrix $A$ is denoted by $[A]_{i,j}$.

> Suppose that $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix with real entries.
>
> (1) If the inequality
> $$\begin{align*}
>         [A]_{i,i} >
>         \sum_{\substack{1 \leq u \leq n \\
>             u \neq i}} {|[A]_{i,u}|}.
>     \end{align*}$$
> holds for every positive integer $i$ less than or equal to $n$, then $\det {(A)} > 0$.
>
> (2) If the inequality
> $$ \begin{align*}
>         [A]_{j,j}\,[A]_{k,k} >
>         \Bigg(
>         \sum_{\substack{1 \leq p \leq n \\
>                 p \neq j}} {|[A]_{j,p}|}
>         \Bigg)
>         \Bigg(
>         \sum_{\substack{1 \leq q \leq n \\
>                 q \neq k}} {|[A]_{k,q}|}
>         \Bigg).
>     \end{align*}$$
> holds for every pair of distinct positive integers $j$, $k$ less than or equal to $n$, and $[A]_{i,i} > 0$ for every positive interger $i$ less than or equal to $n$, then $\det {(A)} > 0$.

I can solve the first part. Here is my proof.

---

Let $P(n)$ be the proposition:

> The determinant of $A$ is greater than zero for every $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with real entries and with the property that the inequality
> $$\begin{align*}
>         [A]_{i,i} >
>         \sum_{\substack{1 \leq u \leq n \\
>             u \neq i}} {|[A]_{i,u}|}.
>     \end{align*}$$
> holds for every positive integer $i$ less than or equal to $n$.

We prove that $P(n)$ is true for every positive integer $n$ by mathematical induction.

$P(1)$ is obviously true.

We show that $P(2)$ is true.
Let
$$
\begin{align*}
    A = \begin{bmatrix}
            a & b \\
            c & d \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
$$
be a $2 \times 2$ matrix with real entries such that
$$
\begin{align*}
    a > |b| \quad \text{and} \quad d > |c|.
\end{align*}
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align*}
    \det {(A)} = ad - bc > |b|\,|c| - bc
    = |bc| - bc \geq 0.
\end{align*}
$$

Assume that $P(n-1)$ is true. We have to show that $P(n)$ is true.

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with real entries.
Suppose that the inequality
$$
\begin{align*}
    [A]_{i,i} >
    \sum_{\substack{1 \leq u \leq n \\
        u \neq i}} {|[A]_{i,u}|}.
\end{align*}
$$
holds for every positive integer $i$ less than or equal to $n$.

Note that $[A]_{1,1}$ is certainly nonzero, since it is greater than some nonnegative number.

Let $B$ be the $n \times n$ matrix obtained from $A$ by adding $-[A]_{i,1}/[A]_{1,1}$ times row $1$ to row $i$ for $i = 2$, $3$, $\dots$, $n$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
    [B]_{1,j}  & = [A]_{1,j};                 \\
    [B]_{i,1}  & = 0,          & \quad i > 1; \\
    [B]_{i,j}  & =
    [A]_{i,j} - \frac{[A]_{i,1}}{[A]_{1,1}} [A]_{1,j},
                    & \quad i > 1;                 \\
    \det {(B)} & = \det {(A)}.
\end{align*}
$$

Let $C$ be the $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ matrix obtained from $B$ by removing the first row and the first column of $B$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
    [C]_{i,j}  & = [B]_{i+1,j+1}
    = [A]_{i+1,j+1} - \frac{[A]_{i+1,1}}{[A]_{1,1}} [A]_{1,j+1};
    \\
    \det {(A)} & = \det {(B)} = [A]_{1,1} \det {(C)}.
\end{align*}
$$

For $j \neq k$,
$$
\begin{align*}
    [A]_{k,k} >
    \sum_{\substack{1 \leq u \leq n \\
        u \neq k}} {|[A]_{k,u}|}
    \geq |[A]_{k,j}|,
\end{align*}
$$
so
$$
\begin{align*}
    [C]_{i,i}
    = {}    &
    [A]_{i+1,i+1} - \frac{[A]_{i+1,1}}{[A]_{1,1}} [A]_{1,i+1}
    \\
    = {}    &
    \frac{[A]_{i+1,i+1} [A]_{1,1} - [A]_{1,i+1} [A]_{i+1,1}}
    {[A]_{1,1}}
    \\
    > {}    &
    \frac{|[A]_{1,i+1}|\, |[A]_{i+1,1}| - [A]_{1,i+1} [A]_{i+1,1}}
    {[A]_{1,1}}
    \\
    = {}    &
    \frac{|{[A]_{1,i+1} [A]_{i+1,1}}| - [A]_{1,i+1} [A]_{i+1,1}}
    {[A]_{1,1}}
    \\
    \geq {} &
    0.
\end{align*}
$$
Hence $0 < [C]_{i,i} = |[C]_{i,i}|$.

Note that
$$
\begin{align*}
    |[C]_{i,i}|
    = {}    &
    \Bigg|
    [A]_{i+1,i+1} - \frac{[A]_{i+1,1}}{[A]_{1,1}} [A]_{1,i+1}
    \Bigg|
    \\
    \geq {} &
    |[A]_{i+1,i+1}| -
    \Bigg|
    \frac{[A]_{i+1,1}}{[A]_{1,1}} [A]_{1,i+1}
    \Bigg|
    \\
    = {}    &
    |[A]_{i+1,i+1}| -
    \frac{|[A]_{i+1,1}|}{|[A]_{1,1}|} |[A]_{1,i+1}|,
\end{align*}
$$
and that
$$
\begin{align*}
            &
    \sum_{\substack{1 \leq v \leq n-1  \\ v \neq i}}
    {|[C]_{i,v}|}
    \\
    = {}    &
    \sum_{\substack{2 \leq \ell \leq n \\ \ell \neq i+1}}
    {|[C]_{i,\ell-1}|}
    \\
    = {}    &
    \sum_{\substack{2 \leq \ell \leq n \\ \ell \neq i+1}}
    {\Bigg|
    [A]_{i+1,\ell} - \frac{[A]_{i+1,1}}{[A]_{1,1}} [A]_{1,\ell}
    \Bigg|}
    \\
    \leq {} &
    \sum_{\substack{2 \leq \ell \leq n \\ \ell \neq i+1}}
    {\Bigg(
        |[A]_{i+1,\ell}| +
        \Bigg|
        \frac{[A]_{i+1,1}}{[A]_{1,1}} [A]_{1,\ell}
        \Bigg|
        \Bigg)}
    \\
    = {}    &
    \sum_{\substack{2 \leq \ell \leq n \\ \ell \neq i+1}}
    {\Bigg(
        |[A]_{i+1,\ell}| +
        \frac{|[A]_{i+1,1}|}{|[A]_{1,1}|} |[A]_{1,\ell}|
        \Bigg)}
    \\
    = {}    &
    \sum_{\substack{2 \leq \ell \leq n \\ \ell \neq i+1}}
    {
    |[A]_{i+1,\ell}|
    }
    +
    \frac{|[A]_{i+1,1}|}{|[A]_{1,1}|}
    \sum_{\substack{2 \leq \ell \leq n \\ \ell \neq i+1}}
    {
    |[A]_{1,\ell}|
    }
    \\
    = {}    &
    \sum_{\substack{1 \leq \ell \leq n \\ \ell \neq i+1}}
    {
    |[A]_{i+1,\ell}|
    }
    - |[A]_{i+1,1}|
    +
    \frac{|[A]_{i+1,1}|}{|[A]_{1,1}|}
    \sum_{2 \leq \ell \leq n}
    {
    |[A]_{1,\ell}|
    }
    % \\
    % {}      &
    % \hphantom{=}
    -
    \frac{|[A]_{i+1,1}|}{|[A]_{1,1}|}
    |[A]_{1,i+1}|
    \\
    = {}    &
    \sum_{\substack{1 \leq \ell \leq n \\ \ell \neq i+1}}
    {
    |[A]_{i+1,\ell}|
    }
    - \frac{|[A]_{i+1,1}|}{|[A]_{1,1}|} |[A]_{1,1}|
    +
    \frac{|[A]_{i+1,1}|}{|[A]_{1,1}|}
    \sum_{2 \leq \ell \leq n}
    {
    |[A]_{1,\ell}|
    }
    % \\
    % {}      &
    % \hphantom{=}
    -
    \frac{|[A]_{i+1,1}|}{|[A]_{1,1}|}
    |[A]_{1,i+1}|
    \\
    = {}    &
    \sum_{\substack{1 \leq \ell \leq n \\ \ell \neq i+1}}
    {
    |[A]_{i+1,\ell}|
    }
    - \frac{|[A]_{i+1,1}|}{|[A]_{1,1}|}
    \Bigg(
    |[A]_{1,1}|
    -
    \sum_{2 \leq \ell \leq n}
    {
        |[A]_{1,\ell}|
    }
    \Bigg)
    % \\
    % {}      &
    % \hphantom{=}
    -
    \frac{|[A]_{i+1,1}|}{|[A]_{1,1}|}
    |[A]_{1,i+1}|
    \\
    \leq {} &
    \sum_{\substack{1 \leq \ell \leq n \\ \ell \neq i+1}}
    {
    |[A]_{i+1,\ell}|
    }
    -
    \frac{|[A]_{i+1,1}|}{|[A]_{1,1}|}
    |[A]_{1,i+1}|.
\end{align*}
$$
Hence
$$
\begin{align*}
    |[C]_{i,i}| -
    \sum_{\substack{1 \leq v \leq n-1  \\ v \neq i}}
    {|[C]_{i,v}|}
    \geq
    |[A]_{i+1,i+1}| -
    \sum_{\substack{1 \leq \ell \leq n \\ \ell \neq i+1}}
    {
    |[A]_{i+1,\ell}|
    }
    > 0.
\end{align*}
$$

Thus by assumption, $\det {(C)} > 0$.

Because $[A]_{1,1} > 0$
and $\det {(C)} > 0$,
we conclude that $\det {(A)} = [A]_{1,1} \det {(C)} > 0$.

We have shown that $P(n)$ is true.

By mathematical induction, $P(n)$ is true for $n = 1$, $2$, $3$, $\dots$.

---

However, I am not able to solve the second part. Mathematical induction does not seem to work. Perhaps it should be solved differently, but I have no idea.

Comment: The first part is a fast consequence of the [Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem). That phrase might give you something to search on—alternative proofs that might generalize, possible existing generalizations.

Comment: Part 2 can be done with Brauer's oval theorem  https://planetmath.org/brauersovalstheorem  .  For simplicity I would first left multiply your matrix $A$ by a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $A':=(DA)$ has all diagonal elements equal to $1$.  This of course does not change the sign of the determinant and $A'$ still observes the inequality of (2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the hints in the comments.

---

We note that (2) implies (1), so it suffices to prove (2).

We do it with [Brauer's oval theorem](https://planetmath.org/brauersovalstheorem). Suppose that an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with real entries meets the requirements in (2). Let $\lambda = x + \mathrm{i} y$ (in which $x$, $y \in \mathbb{R}$) be an eigenvalue of $A$. Put
$$
\begin{align*}
R_i = \sum_{\substack{1 \leq u \leq n \\ u \neq i}} {|[A]_{i,u}|}.
\end{align*}
$$
We claim that $x > 0$, from which we can conclude that $\det {(A)} > 0$.  If $x \leq 0$, it would be true by [Brauer's oval theorem](https://planetmath.org/brauersovalstheorem) that
$$
\begin{align*}
R_j R_k
\geq {} &
|{\lambda - [A]_{j,j}}|\,|{\lambda - [A]_{k,k}}|
\\
= {} &
|{[A]_{j,j} - \lambda}|\,|{[A]_{k,k} - \lambda}|
\\
= {} &
|{([A]_{j,j} - x) - \mathrm{i}y}|\, |{([A]_{k,k} - x) + \mathrm{i}y}|
\\
\geq {} &
|{[A]_{j,j} - x}|\,|{[A]_{k,k} - x}|
\\
= {} &
([A]_{j,j} - x)\,([A]_{k,k} - x)
\\
\geq {} &
[A]_{j,j}\,[A]_{k,k}
\\
> {} &
R_j R_k
\end{align*}
$$
for some distinct integers $j$, $k$. A contradiction.

---

My old proof of (1) is just brute force. It gives me little insight about (2).